# Unknown field with rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm attempting to do some web scraping via *rvest* but it appears the fields are not being recognised, and trips up on the *set_values* function:

```
session <- html_session("http://www.itto.int/annual_review_output/?mode=searchdata")
form <- html_form(session)[[2]]
set_values(form, countries = "1", products = "1" ,flows = "1", years = "1"))
submit_form(session, form)
```

Which generates the following error.

> Error: Unknown field names: countries, products, flows, years
>   submit_form(session, form)

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When inspect this site you can see :

> select size="15" id="countries" name="countries[]" multiple="multiple" onChange="selectCancel('groups');

so `name` of elemets is  `countries[]`

in `set_values` additional arguments is

> Name-value pairs giving fields to modify

So I think you need to use smt like

```
set_values(form, "countries[]" = "1", "products[]" = "1" ,"flows[]" = "1", "years[]" = "1")
```